# Fabric 'Activity in your app right now' map not working on chrome on windows

Tags: google-fabric

We want to be able to display app usage on a large TV in the office, going to use the Audience panel in fabric.  Works great in safari on OSX but not so great in chrome or internet explorer on a windows box.  Anyone know of a setting that might be blocking this feed?  (Thinking it might be HTML5)

Comment: For me in Google Chrome on Windows 10 does not work. I would also get a solution for this.